# Using ruby "send" on Nokogiri objects as page.send(a) where a="at('div.class-name')"

Tags: ruby, class, nokogiri, mechanize, send

Now, this is my HTML,

```
<div class = 'div-of-all-names'>
  <div class='best-first-name'>
    <span itemprop='name'> Alexander </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this hash in my Ruby Program,

```
URL = "http://www.xxx.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx"
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(URL)

patterns = {1 => ['at("div.div-of-all-names")'],
            2 => ['at("div.best-first-name")'] ,
            3 => ['search("span[@itemprop='name']")']}

# Selecting those keys that is a number and sorting
p = patterns.keys.select{|i|  /[0-9]/ =~ i.to_s }.sort
# p = [1,2,3]

p.each do |i|
  p[i].each do |j|
    out = page.send(j)
    if !(out.blank?)  
      page = out
      p j
      break
    end
  end
end
name = page.inner_text
p name
```

Questions:

**1. Can I not use ruby's "send" on a Nokogiri object?** 
  Because, I can use the ruby hashes and store the actual "search" or "at" with the "class", "id" ,"itemprop" or whatever html attributes in the hash as levels, 1,2 and 3.
Once they are stored as levels, I will retrieve from them as loop variables in "i" or "j" and use a ".send(j)" on the Nokogiri Objects.

I tried this and got this error,

```
1.9.3p385 :238 > a
 => "at(\"div.our_price\")" 
1.9.3p385 :239 > page.send(a)
NoMethodError: undefined method `at("div.our_price")' for #<Mechanize::Page:0xb2ba6dc>
    from (irb):239
```

**2. If Im using "at", can I only manipulate classes?** Like,

> ```
> "page.at('span.humble')" 
> **means** 
> <-span-class ='humble'>
>      Humble
>   <-/-span>
> **then what about** 
> <-span-id='humble'>
>      Humble
>   <-/-span>
> ```

Comment: Your combining the method name and parameters. For send, they have to be separate.

Comment: hey thats a great observation. Let me do a little something and get back. I know where I went wrong. Meanwhile, give me an answer for question 2.

Comment: I have no idea for #2, I don't use Nokogiri.

Comment: @Linuxios : Dude I got it worked, if passed the method name is a and the parameters in b as page.send(a,b). Thank you so much for your help. Put this as a separate answer, maybe I will tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the method name and parameters to send separately:

```
obj.send("methodname", "arg1", "arg2")
```

Answer (score 1):

> If Im using "at", can I only manipulate classes?

```
"page.at('span.humble')" 
**means** 
<-span-class ='humble'>
     Humble
  <-/-span>
**then what about** 
<-span-id='humble'>
     Humble
  <-/-span>
```

OK, first, don't make up ways to highlight your HTML. Use normal formatting and plain-old HTML and, if necessary, put it into a separate section, otherwise you'll confuse us and someone will tell you the problem is invalid HTML. It should look something like this in your question at a minimum:

```
    page.at('span.humble') 

means:

    <span class ='humble'>
         Humble
    </span>

then what about:

    <span id='humble'>
         Humble
    </span>
```

With *that* out of the way...

Why would you think that you can't use IDs? You're defining a CSS accessor, so use one for ID:

```
page.at('span#humble')
```

[`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at), like [`search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search), is not limited to classes or IDs. If you can define it as CSS (including lots of jQuery extensions), then Nokogiri should be able to find it. Nokogiri also supports XPath accessors so you can jump between the two styles as needed to pinpoint the node you want.

I recommend CSS because it's generally cleaner and less noisy. You can use either with `at` and `search`, even though you'll often see people use the more explicit [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) and [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) or [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) and [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) instead of `search`. I'm lazy and only use the more generic versions.

I highly recommend spending some time perusing [Nokogiri's documentation](http://nokogiri.org). It's very powerful and allows you to munge HTML/XML all day long.

Comment: Oh my God, great lesson, what about <span itemprop="dude"> Dude</span>, how to represent this with "at"

Comment: And how to represent this in "at"...search("div[@class='costs']//span[@class='days']")

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're setting these up for `instance_eval` rather than send:

```
page.instance_eval 'at("div.div-of-all-names")'
```

Comment: Oh you were late, send looks more clear and readable for my code. But learnt instance_eval. Thanks.